# Add New Field to MongoDB Collection Array Based on Existence of Another Field in Array Using Aggregation

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document in collectionA of the following format:

```json
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("641893db137e63c5d6940f68"),
        "summaryId" : 20,
        "actions" : [
                {
                        "action" : "Action A",
                        "actionDate" : "2023-02-25 20:59:49"
                },
                {
                        "action" : "Action B",
                        "actionDate" : "2021-11-18 20:49:55",
                        "actorRoleId" : 5
                },
                {
                        "action" : "Action C",
                        "actionDate" : "2021-11-25 20:49:55",
                        "actorRoleId" : 4
                },
                {
                        "action" : "Action D",
                        "actionDate" : "2023-02-25 20:49:55"
                }
        ]
}
```

I want to add a new field 'actorUserId' to each element of the 'actions' array, but only where the 'actorRoleId' field exists.  I would like to utilize aggregation to do this.  I have the following python code, but it adds the new field to every element of the 'actions' array, even if the 'actorRoleId' field does not exist.

```py
    pipeline = [
        {
            "$match": {
                "actions.actorRoleId": {"$exists": True}
            }
        },
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "actions.actorUserId": "Testing"
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "summaryId": True,
                "actions": True
            }
        },
        {"$merge": "summary"},
    ]

    db.collectionA.aggregate(pipeline)
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$map` to iterate through the array and chain up `$mergeObjects` with `$cond` to conditionally add the new field(s).

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "actions": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$actions",
          "as": "a",
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $ne: [
                  {
                    $ifNull: [
                      "$$a.actorRoleId",
                      null
                    ]
                  },
                  null
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$a",
                  {
                    // extra fields you want to add
                    "actorUserId": "Testing"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "else": "$$a"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SRe1siTyVbv)